# Every time on start up my pc sets a proxy which is https://127.0.0.1:86/

Tags: windows, windows-10, proxy

Going into this website makes you download a file which has this code in it.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) { 
//Ver:1.0.0.4
if (shExpMatch(url, "*/recaptcha/*")) return "DIRECT"; 
if (shExpMatch(host, "cse.google.*")) return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:83"; 
if (shExpMatch(host, "www.google.*")) return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:83"; 
if (shExpMatch(host, "*search.yahoo.com")) return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:83"; 
if (shExpMatch(host, "www.bing.*")) return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:83"; 
if (shExpMatch(host, "www.ebay.*")) return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:83"; 
if (shExpMatch(host, "www.youtube.*")) return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:83"; 
if (shExpMatch(host, "www.amazon.*")) return "PROXY 127.0.0.1:83"; 
return "DIRECT";}
```

I have a short term solution to this problem which is running a .reg file which runs

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
"ProxyOverride"=-
"ProxyServer"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
"ProxyOverride"=-
"ProxyServer"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
"ProxyOverride"=-
"ProxyServer"=-

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
"ProxyOverride"=-
"ProxyServer"=-

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
"ProxyOverride"=-
"ProxyServer"=-

[HKEY_USERS\...\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
"ProxyOverride"=-
"ProxyServer"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxySettingsPerUser"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel]
"Connection Settings"=dword:00000000
```

This is the only solution I found other than resetting my pc or running a full scan which sometimes could work. Does anyone know what this proxy can be used for?

Comment: See if you can deduce the process PID listening on port 83 by running `netstat -ano` from a command prompt. Then look at the Task Manager for a matching process PID.

Comment: This type of behavior is most likely a virus, spyware or malware. Scan your computer for these threats with a good virusscanner such as hitman pro, malware bytes or good av.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I just resolved the same problem on my network: you have to change your router password.

I hope this solution works for you too.

Comment: While you may have answered the question, if you could provide a reason for it fixing it and why etc it could help others with similar questions and computer users in general. Thanks for helping out on superuser.

Comment: You are right, sorry for too soon and incomplete reply. 
The problem is STILL present and I've tried any kind of antivirus/antispyware and so on... I hope to find a woking solution.